# How to validate special chars(<,>) which are in content pages from a Master Page

Tags: javascript, master-pages, validation, content-pages

I am having one Master Page say MasterOne.master
with 2 content pages Login.aspx and Registration.aspx

In both my content pages i want to validate Text boxes with NOT allowing Special Chars( esp < , >)

For this i just wanted to write Java script in my master page so that my  content pages are validated.

SO how could i do this for all text boxes using Java script...

Any help